# predicative use of "adverse"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, predicate

Can we use the word "adverse" in predicative?

> The conditions on the moon are adverse for people to live

In the sentence, is the use of "adverse" correct?

Answer (score 1):

I searched in the [COCA corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and found 23 results for **are adverse**. Only some of these are examples of predicative use, but they do exist:

> Hydrological mechanisms that lead to lower pore-water pressures in the soil are beneficial, whereas those that increase pore pressure **are adverse**. Of the mechanical mechanisms, those that increase shear resistance in the slope are beneficial, whereas those that increase shear stress **are adverse** (Greenway 1987).

As for the "for-complement", I found no examples for "are adverse for" and only one for "is adverse for":

> "Most CEOs are honest and hardworking. Creating the idea that all CEOs are bad **is adverse for society**, " says Crandall, who, while widely respected, was not universally loved by his troops.

However, there are 19 examples for "is adverse to" and 10 examples for "are adverse to".

---

In the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/), I found the following:

> But Texas hospitality does not perish even when conditions **are adverse**.
>
> When polls **are adverse** there's a tendency to say there's something wrong at the top.

No examples for "adverse for" and "are adverse to", but 10 examples for "is adverse to":

> Where the decision **is adverse to** the claimant, information about the right of appeal to the Commissioners must be given.